# When DTLforeach is used with a condition, DTLiflastrow does not work

Tags: datatool

In the following code, my dataset is {1,2,3,4}.

With no filter, DTLiffirstrow will return true at "1" and DTLiflastrow will return true at "4".
This is what I expect from these functions.

When I filter the dataset to {2,3},
DTLiffisrtrow returns true at "2". Perfect.

But DTLiflastrow is always false. I would expect it to return true for the value "3".

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLnewdb{table}
\DTLnewrow{table}
\DTLnewdbentry{table}{C1}{1}
\DTLnewrow{table}
\DTLnewdbentry{table}{C1}{2}
\DTLnewrow{table}
\DTLnewdbentry{table}{C1}{3}
\DTLnewrow{table}
\DTLnewdbentry{table}{C1}{4}


\begin{document}


\DTLforeach*%
[\DTLisclosedbetween{\COne}{2}{3}]%
{table}%
{\COne=C1}%
{%
    \COne%
    \DTLiffirstrow{FIRST}{}%
    \DTLiflastrow{LAST}{}%
    \\%
}%

\end{document}
```

How could I detect the last row of a filtered set of data?

Comment: There's no way for `datatool` to know it's on the last filtered row on a single pass. It would require two passes: first to find out which is the last row of the filtered set and the second to compare the current row with that value. (`datatool` knows how many rows the database has but the last row may be filtered. `\DTLiflastrow` can only compare the current row index with the total number of rows.)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a bug, it's a feature !

See the doc (datatool-code.pdf, around page 199):

```
\DTLiflastrow{〈true part 〉}{〈false part 〉}
```

> Checks if the current row is the last row of the database. It **doesn’t**
> **take the condition** (the optional argument of \DTLforeach) **into
> account**, so its possible it may never do 〈true part〉, as the last row
> of the database may not meet the condition.
>
> It is therefore not very
> useful and is confusing since it behaves differently to \DTLiffirstrow
> which does take the condition ...